# std::mutex :: when the lock acquired thread gets killed what would happen to other waiting threads with respect to std::mutex locks

Tags: c++, multithreading

Multiple threads are trying to access a critical area and assume we use `std::mutex` to lock it.
Now one of the thread acquired the lock and after sometime if it gets killed .. what would be the system behavior? Similar to pthread mutex robust do we have anything for `std::mutex`?

Comment: AFAIK standard C++ doesn't define any way to kill a thread in the first place.  If your implementation provides such a thing as an extension, then you have to look to its documentation to see how it handles held locks.

Comment: What do you mean by `"...one of the thread acquired the lock and after sometime if it gets killed"`?  How is that thread 'killed'?

Comment: But there is a possibility for the thread getting terminated for some unknown reasons right ? If so and if tat thread was holding lock that's were I am interested !  Thread termination by kernal die to some signal or any reason.. a thread termination is always possible correct ?

Comment: "_getting terminated for some unknown reasons_" - If you don't have control over the program you likely have undefined behavior and most likely, the mutex will be locked forever, just like if you lock it and exit the thread on purpose [example](https://godbolt.org/z/cbj44WY8x)

Comment: "But there is a possibility for the thread getting terminated for some unknown reasons right ?"  The C++ standard doesn't define any such possibility.  So any answer to this question will not be found in the language itself, but in the documentation of specific implementations (and you haven't said what you are using).

Comment: My interest is more to know , what would happen if some such termination occurs .  With POSIX mutex lock I am aware that if we use robust mutex we can handle the scenario if the thread holding the lock dies .. does STD::Mutex supports any such behaviors!

Comment: "My interest is more to know , what would happen if some such termination occurs ."  Then I'll say once more: **tell us what implementation (compiler/OS/library/etc) you want to know about**.   The question is unanswerable without that information, or at best, the answer is only the trivial "the behavior is undefined".

Comment: _"...The behavior of a program is undefined if a mutex is destroyed while still owned by any threads, or a __thread terminates while owning a mutex__...."_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Similar to pthread mutex robust do we have anything for `std::mutex`?

No we don't.  Not on the systems, I know about, anyway.

On POSIX systems, the 'robustness' of a mutex has to be set when the mutex is created.  Since the mutex is created by the `std::mutex` constructor, and this has no 'robustness' parameter, this is not possible.

On Windows, there is no 'robustness' setting for mutexes / critical section objects, period.